# Ionic problem with buttons inside ion-content

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a problem with my code....buttons inside ion-content not working. I think it´s because a split-pane but i don´t know. Here you get my code. I refere to the button with "navigate()" click event at the bottom of the code.

````
    <!-- LATERAL MENU -->
    <ion-split-pane>
    </ion-split-pane>
    <!-- HEADER ZONE -->
    <ion-header>
    </ion-header>
    <!-- CONTENT ZONE -->
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-grid>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col>
                        Genera tu código QR
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col class="bold">
                        ¡Canjea tus puntos
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col class="bold">
                        acumulados!
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-icon name="information-circle-outline" class="icon"></ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col class="parraf">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-button expand="block" class="generate" (click)="navigate()">GENERAR MI CÓDIGO</ion-button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>```
````

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using? That doesn't look like a correct split pane setup. Where's your router outlet? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/split-pane

Comment: i have omitted the code from the split-pane because the real problem is about the button in the bottom of the code

Comment: Ok well there's nothing from the code you've posted that indicates what the problem is. Show your `navigate()` method. What exactly isn't working in that method?